# Ruby on Rails: Devise - Is it bad to have a Users Controller separate from devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

So from the beginning of the project, I installed `devise gem`, did the migrations and everything. Would it be bad practice, if I created a new controller:

```
rails g controller Users
```

Along side with devise? Sorry for the n00b question. Is there like a secrete place that devise creates this controller already and I can just customize and modify?

Comment: [There are multiple controllers, actually](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that it depends what you're trying to accomplish. If you want to customize Devise, Devise provides some hooks that you can use to customize certain things such as after_sign_up_path etc, or you can subclass Devise built-in controllers, for example:

```
class MyRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
end
```

If you want something that devise doesn't provide, eg a list of users, or a detail page for a user, you might want to just create your own users controller as you mentioned - not bad practice, and Devise doesn't have any secrets, you can poke around in the gem code on Devise to find out what it's providing and what you might want to add or customize.

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably ned to do something like that!